# Disable Logging in Kundera for Cassandra

Tags: kundera

All CRUD operations being logged in our application logs by Kundera, which floods our logs. Is there a way to turn it off ?

I should at least be able to direct it to another file instead of crowding my application logs files.

Is there any way to do it through configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

Please add a logback.xml(for kunder-cassandra module) to classpath and turn the logging level to error(to prevent these logs)

https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/blob/4bc732ebeea971d0449e4bf67a70023e83a72a8b/src/kundera-cassandra/cassandra-core/src/test/resources/logback.xml​